# Input values are not updated in managed bean

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2.2

The field values of my HTML page are not sent to my managed bean. By invoking the action, the values are `null`. My html code is:

```
<form jsf:id="form">
    <fieldset>
        <label> <span
                class="block input-icon input-icon-right"> <input
                    type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Usuário"
                    jsf:id="usr" jsf:value="#{loginBean.user}" />
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
            </span>
        </label> <label> <span
                class="block input-icon input-icon-right"> <input
                    type="password" class="span12" placeholder="Senha"
                    jsf:id="pwd" jsf:value="#{loginBean.password}" />
                    <i class="icon-lock"></i>
            </span>
        </label>

        <div class="space"></div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <button jsf:action="#{loginBean.doLogin()}" jsf:id="btn"
                    class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-small btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-key"></i> Login
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="space-4"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I was put and `syout` on my `LoginBean.doAction` method and it print `null` for `user` and `password` attributes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which annotations exactly have you placed on the managed `LoginBean` class? Symptoms suggest that you merely placed `@Named` on it without an explicit scope.

Comment: My managed bean has '@Named' and '@RequestScoped' annotations

Comment: What package did you import that `@RequestScoped` annotation from? Symptoms suggest that it's not from the CDI package.

Comment: `import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean extends ManagedBean {`

It´s from CDI package.
The only dependency on my pom.xml is

`<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>7.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Should work. This all works fine for me. Add a `@PostConstruct public void init() {}` and put a breakpoint on there and check how many times it's invoked during submit.

Comment: By the way, when the page is rendered the method `doLogin()` is invoked too. I add the `@PostConstruct` method and, during submit, the method is invoked one time

Comment: Ahh, did you declare the `xmlns:jsf` namespace?

Comment: Yes: `xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf"`

Comment: That had a bug in older Mojarra versions. Which container are you deploying to and what JSF impl/version are you using? The official Java EE 7 namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf` should work. Give it a try and let me know, then I'll bake an answer.

Comment: I´m using a GlassFish 4 container with default implementations. I will change the Glassfish Mojarra-Impl version and test again. Thanks!

Comment: Did the official Java EE 7 namespace work? You should not be using `java.sun.com` based namespaces anymore.

Comment: I tried your code (on JSF 2.2.8-02 running on GlassFish 4.1).  `passThrough` itself is disregarded for some unclear reasons. The IDE itself issues a notification, `Unused library declaration xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`. Hence, those attributes like `jsf:id` are not parsed and directly included in the generated HTML. The rest is the same and needless to mention -  the `actionListener` method is invoked but those field values are always `null`  in the method. Changing the bean from JSF managed bean to CDI managed bean does not even invoke the listener method.

Comment: Thanks guys! I changed the namespace to "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" and it works fine!

Comment: Are you not merely making it up? :) It does not even work on a blank playground project with a single XHTML file in it and no external dependencies at all even using this namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough` on JSF 2.2.8-02 (while the answer provided by BalusC is perfectly valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you declared the XML namespace `xmlns:jsf` on URI `http://java.sun.com/jsf`, based on the old `java.sun.com` host.

This has a bug in older Mojarra versions. New JSF 2.2 specific features such as `<f:viewAction>` and "[HTML5 friendly markup](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm)" weren't initially available on XML namespace with the old `java.sun.com` host in the URI, but only on `xmlns.jcp.org` host. This was fixed in Mojarra 2.2.1-2.2.2.

As you're on Java EE 7, you should really abandon `java.sun.com` host in XML namespace URIs and use `xmlns.jcp.org` instead.

```
<html ... xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
```

That said, that this bug occurs also indicates that you're using a rather old Mojarra version. It's wise to upgrade it. It's currently already at 2.2.9 (which in turn has the awkward bug that line numbers aren't included in class files, so you couldn't step through the source in IDE's debugger, you'd better pick 2.2.8 if this is mandatory; this will be fixed in 2.1.10).

Comment: Does the OP's code really work on a decent Mojarra version - perhaps some container related issues might otherwise be larking somewhere else? I also made sure to change the DTD. Nothing helped even using Mojarra 2.2.8-02 on GlassFish 4.1 (it is just a plain newly created application having only a single XHTML file and having no extra dependencies not even PrimeFaces/OmniFaces - nothing).

Comment: @Tiny: I tested with Mojarra 2.2.8 on Tomcat. Does your `faces-config.xml` comply JSF 2.2?

Comment: Yes it implies the version 2.2 (`version="2.2"`) with other relevant 2.2 namespaces.